# Cannot turn on the visibilty option in bluetooth settings

Tags: bluetooth, 16.10

I can turn on and off the bluetooth but cannot turn on the visibility of the device. For this reason, my device is not able to connect with other bluetooth devices. How can I get the visibility option enable?

The out put for

`lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'; hciconfig -a` is below.

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 174f:114f Syntek 
Bus 003 Device 012: ID 0000:0538  
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0e8f:0022 GreenAsia Inc. multimedia keyboard controller
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.159709] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    6.120927] usb 1-1.3: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[   14.437686] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[   14.437703] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   14.437707] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   14.437709] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   14.437714] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   16.579597] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1005 tx timeout
[   18.595716] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c23 tx timeout
[   20.607908] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c14 tx timeout
[   22.784061] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c25 tx timeout
[   23.985055] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   23.985057] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   23.985061] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   24.800188] Bluetooth: hci0 command tx timeout
[  482.272615] usb 1-1.3: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[  483.025292] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  483.025307] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  483.025319] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[10877.522483] usb 1-1.3: device firmware changed
[10878.160012] usb 1-1.3: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[10897.605386] usb 1-1.3: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 48:D2:24:25:39:02  ACL MTU: 1022:8  SCO MTU: 183:5
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:682 acl:0 sco:0 events:48 errors:0
    TX bytes:2954 acl:0 sco:0 commands:48 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xfe 0x0d 0xfe 0xd8 0x7f 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/854916/edit) the question to include results for `lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'; hciconfig -a`

Comment: @Jeremy31 now I have edited the question

Comment: @DavidFoerster I have edited my question

Comment: What Ubuntu version and kernel `uname -a; cat /etc/lsb-release` And what wireless card is this part of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

Comment: Ubuntu version and kernel "Ubuntu 16.10", wireless card Subsystem: Lenovo AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:3218]
 Kernel driver in use: ath9k
 Kernel modules: ath9k

Comment: Try this in terminal `bluetoothctl` then enter `discoverable on`  If that works file a bug report, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug  I am using the same combo on Ubuntu 16.04 and I can use bluetooth manager to turn discovery on.  Use CTRL + d or quit to exit bluetoothctl

Comment: @Jeremy31 working fine